# How can i store 32 MB file in Blackberry project

Tags: java, database, blackberry, download, large-files

Recently i am developing application for android and blackberry. 
What i need to do is to store a 32MB Sqlite file in project as initial database for application uses. In case of android it is simple and i can easily store this large file in assest folder but i m having hard time trying to make this work in blackberry why because as per RIM announcement App size should not be larger then 15 MB.

http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-os-apps-f35/rim-explains-app-memory-limit-637544/

Can anybody help me if is there any other trick strikes to make this happen.
To download a 32 MB file during Application startup is not a good idea. It'll take long time to navigate user into application.

Many thanks in advance.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The only think you could do is to download the data from a WS the first time the user opens the app and then save it to sqlite db or file. But is such a large ammount of data, the user will just quit, or they could be charged by the carrier, etc. Do you really need 32MB?

Comment: yes i need this large data file, we've web support we can take data from web server as well. But client require local storage of the database as well so working for unavailability of network.

Comment: I would certainly recommend downloading the file in the **background**, so you don't block the UI thread.  Let the user continue to use the app while the database downloads.  It maybe large enough, that you also might want to split the file into multiple parts, so that if the user quits or loses connectivity before the download completes, you won't have to download 100% of it next time.  Then, reassemble the file when you're finished downloading all of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this yesterday after work, and I think you could also try including the same data the DB contains, but in a compressed format, such as the first time the app is run, you create and populate the larger local sqlite DB from it, then delete the compressed data.

For instance, you could create a CSV dump of each table, and save it to a .csv file (i.e.: table.csv). Then you could then gzip each one to a file (i.e.: table.gz). You then compile every compressed file in a second resource module for your app (i.e: res_module.cod). When you install the app, this module is also installed and it copies its files to SDCard. Then the main module reads the files from the SDCard, ungzipping them and populating each table from them. After that, you can programmatically uninstall the assests module and delete the sdcard temporary files. The requirement for this to work is the compressed files should be smaller than 14 MB to fit in one cod file.

As for the DB schema, maybe a format for exporting it already exists, otherwise you could make your own format, or if the DB is unlikely to change, then hardcode it (bad practice).

Comment: Not a bad idea but little complex. As per RIM's restriction we can store only 7-8 MB raw files in resource folder & i've only 5 MB space after including images in resource folder. May be CSV file would take less then 5 MB.

Comment: That depends on the nature of the data to be compressed. Maybe you could do a quick test and compress the whole .db file in gzip (I initially thought of csv text files assuming sqlite file would be bigger due to overhead). That would give you a rough idea of the achieved compression rate and whether or not it fits in your available space.

Comment: Mister Smith@ i tried for a zipped database to be inserted in my src folder but as soon as i copy zipped in my source folder. It stop to run application and saying:-    no Entry points.....is there something that i missing.

Comment: It's good practice to put resource files in the /res folder, although I'm not sure this would solve your problem. You could try to place the file in a different test application with no sources and try to compile. BTW, what's the size once compressed?

Comment: Zipped file has 4MB of space from a 25MB sqlite file.

Comment: Then 5MB images plus 4MB zipped db should fit in your app. Have you tried placing it in the res folder? Do you still have errors?